# Python: Regex file search with shutil using an excel file

Tags: python, regex, csv, openpyxl, shutil

I have a program I am writing for an internal employee that takes a CSV file and searches a file server for the files listed in the CSV then copys each file to a folder in the desktop. The issue I am running into with my current code is that the CSV must hold the exact names but instead I need to regex search this and copy the files with file names like the ones in the CSV.

file name in excel looks like: D6957-QR-1452

file name on server looks like: WM_QRLabels_D6957-QR-1452_11.5x11.5_M.pdf

```
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import openpyxl
import tkinter as tk
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import os


desktop = Path.home() / "Desktop/Comps"

tk.messagebox.showinfo("Select a directory","Select a directory" )
folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
root = tk.Tk()


root.title("Title")


lbl = tk.Label(
    root, text="Open the excel file that includes files to search for")
lbl.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
listbox = tk.Listbox(frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


def load_file():
    wb_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('Excel files', '.xlsx')])
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb_path)
    global sheet
    sheet = wb.active

    listbox.pack()
    file_names = [cell.value for row in sheet.rows for cell in row]
    for file_name in file_names:
        listbox.insert('end', file_name)
    return file_names  # <--- return your list 
    
            



def search_folder(folder, file_name):
    # Create an empty list to store the found file paths
    found_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            if file in file_name:
                found_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                shutil.copy2(file, desktop)

    return found_files


excelBtn = tk.Button(root, text="Open Excel File",
                     command=None)
excelBtn.pack()


zipBtn = tk.Button(root, text="Copy to Desktop",
                   command=search_folder(folder, load_file()))
zipBtn.pack()


root.mainloop()


Program is able to find and copy exact file names but unable to file *like* files.
```

Comment: So if I got it right... your excel can have entries with wildcards like 'foo*', 'foo.*', or 'foo%', and you should be able to locate 'foobar' and 'foobaz' on the server. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. Basically just need to strip the additional "WM_QRLabels_" and "_11.5x11.5_M.pdf" from the file name that lives on the server to get the right paths. The excel file it searches only has the D6957-QR-1452 part.

Answer (score 0):

Change your search_folder method to something like this:

```
def search_folder(folder, file_name):
    # Create an empty list to store the found file paths
    found_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            for file_pattern in file_name:
                if file.find(file_pattern) > -1:
                    replaced_backslashes = re.sub(r"\\+", "/", os.path.join(root, file), 0, re.MULTILINE)
                    found_files.append(replaced_backslashes)
                    shutil.copy2(file, desktop)

    return found_files
```

Basically, for every file we iterate over the file_name array to test all the patterns.

For the test we use `find` method, that in case it matches, returns the position of the found substring.

That is, if searching for 'foo', all these files would be returned:

```
zazfoo
foobar
zazfoobar
foo
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! However when I make the changes to the code I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\fretzm\Desktop\CodeProjects\ForRick\ProdSearch01.py", line 55, in search_folder
    pattern = re.compile(re.escape(file_name))
  File "C:\Users\fretzm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 276, in escape
    pattern = str(pattern, 'latin1')
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, list found `

Comment: @SynfulAcktor I thougt `file_name` was a scalar :). I edited my answer to fix it. Now I  basically iterate over the file_name array and test every occurrence with `find`

Comment: @Juilo After doing some playing with the code I notice that the path of the files trying to be copied looks like _['Y:/Walmart_WAL/WM_SwipeUp_ExtBanner_QRLabels/Comps\\WM_QRLabels_D6957-QR-0283_11.5x11.5_M.pdf']_ which is causing it to fail in the shutil.copy. I know I need to grep and replace the \\ with / but also not sure if it will still error due to it being in a list and not str. Any added help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @SynfulAcktor If your excel file with patterns has regular slashes, then yes, you probably should replace all backslashes with a single slash. Something like this should work: `replaced_backslashes = re.sub(r"\\+", "/", whatever, 0, re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: I am having issues understanding how to work with the list returned in found_files. `replaced_backslashes = re.sub(r"\\+", "/", found_files[0], 0, re.MULTILINE)` This will do exactly what I need it to do on the first file but does only the first file. Do I need a for loop to pick out each file in found_files and perform the re.sub for each in the list? If so what would that look like?

Comment: @SynfulAcktor, probably best idea is to return the list with already replaced backslashes. Take a look at my answer, I edited it so that backslashes are replaced before appending to `found_files`. You *may* need to do something similar with the argument passed to shutil.copy2.